# Does the arrangement of atoms around a chiral carbon matter?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, chirality

In other words, are these two structures equivalent?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are both (S)-2-chlorobutane.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between these structures is a rotation of the molecule by 60 degrees. You could build a model to convince yourself that they are the same. The arrangement of the atoms around the chiral center *does* matter.

The utility of the R/S convention is that you can unambiguously decide whether the two compounds are the same or different, which can be difficult depending on the orientation of the compound.